# cannot hide div out of viewport

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to hide my absolute positioned div out of viewport when viewport is less than 960px. Here's the css for div and media query with rule of hiding:

```
@media all and (max-width: 960px) {
    .newsbox{
        right:-355px;
    }

}  

.newsbox{
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:900;
    width:395px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#f7f7f7;
}
```

Can anybody explain me why this rule is not hiding this element when browser window is not wider than 960px? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@media` rule needs to be placed below, otherwise the cascade will cause your outer `.newsbox` rule to always take precedence and override the `right` style in your inner `.newsbox` rule, regardless of whether your media query is in effect:

```
.newsbox {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 900;
    width: 395px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

@media all and (max-width: 960px) {
    .newsbox {
        right: -355px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that it was irrelevant in relation to media queries... But know I know it is relevant:) Thank U a lot!